# C# Delay operation without memory leaking

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, timer, garbage-collection, delay

What is the best method to delay an operation by a couple of seconds?
I found the following code on stackoverflow:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
timer.Start();
timer.Tick += (_sender, _args) =>
{
     timer.Stop();
     operation();
};
```

but I don't think that garbage collector is clever enough to remove this timer from memory as it doesn't know that `Tick` depends on `Start` / `Stop` operations and that timer will not be turned on anymore.

I guess I will need to remove an event first, but to do this I'll have to extract lambda to
 a separate method. Is there a better way to simply delay an operation?

Comment: Have a look at `System.Threading.SpinWait`

Answer (score 0):

The question is what "operation" you attempt to delay. If it is the current thread than Soner Gönül's solution is the way to go. It also signals the application to reschedule to another thread.

Answer (score -1):

Why not dispose of the timer and then set to null?

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
timer.Start();
timer.Tick += (_sender, _args) =>
{
     timer.Stop();
     //timer.Dispose(); <-- Not available on a dispatch timer
     timer = null;
     operation();
};
```

Comment: because the timer doesn't have any `Dispose` method

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought it was an ordinary timer.  Still, setting to null should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so because the reference to this timer is gone when the function ends anyway

Comment: In that case, your assertion that your original code will leak memory is also false.  At least setting it to null, will mean if there is a GC during operation() the timer will be ready to free then.

Comment: but if you won't stop the timer in `Tick` function, the timer will remain to tick - that means that it's still in memory and calling `Stop` just pauses it

Comment: You should stop AND set to NULL.  What else can you do in this situation?